# MySQL & PHP Output Headline with Sub Headlines

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 MySQL tables that contain the following:

**Headline:**

```
id | headline | rank | identifier
```

**SubHeadline**

```
id | subheadline | rank | identifier
```

What i need to happen is for the Headline to output with the relevant sub headlines listed below

```
Headline One<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Three for Headline One<br>

Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline Two

Headline Three<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Three
```

At present I can only get my code to output:

```
Headline One<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Three for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Three<br>
Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Three for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Three<br>
Headline Three<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline Three for Headline One<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline Two for Headline Two<br>
Sub Headline One for Headline Three<br>
```

This is my current code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('lunch');
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM headline ORDER BY rank');

while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $output['headline'].'<br />';
    $query2 = mysql_query('SELECT headline.headline, subheadline.subheadline
        FROM headline
        INNER JOIN subheadline
        ON headline.identifier=subheadline.identifier');

    while ($output2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        echo $output2['subheadline'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Change query2 to:

```
$query2 = mysql_query('SELECT subheadline.subheadline
    FROM subheadline
    WHERE subheadline.identifier=' . (int)$output['headline']);
```

But since you already have `headline.id`, why not use it in `subheadline.indentifier`?

Comment: Many thanks,I have changes Query 2 and now get the following output:

Comment: Headline One<br>
Headline Two<Br>
Headline Three